# How to create view partial for this notification

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've already setup a notification for whenever a user posts a review on a book, the book.user gets notified in this partial: views/notifications/_book.html.erb. At the same time, I trying to create  notification to a user's followers for whenever the user they're following posts a new book. IMO, supposed to create a book partial to render the notification view but I already have a duplicate of the book partial to show reviews notifications. Now I don't know if I can still tweak in in the same file or create something else. I'm using https://github.com/rails-engine/notifications.

I've implemented following relationships which is working well on my app from this tutorial https://www.devwalks.com/lets-build-instagram-with-ruby-on-rails-part-6-follow-all-the-people/

This is what I've done so far with the codes

user.rb

```
  has_many :books, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :chapters, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :reviews, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :genres
  has_many :ratings
```

review.rb

```
belongs_to :book
belongs_to :user

after_commit :create_notifications, on: :create

private

def create_notifications
    Notification.create do |notification|
       notification.notify_type = 'book'
       notification.actor = self.user
       notification.user = self.book.user
       notification.target = self
       notification.second_target = self.book
    end
end
```

views/notifications/_book.html.erb

```
<div class=''>
  <%= link_to notification.actor.username, main_app.profile_path(notification.actor.username) %> reviewed
  <%= link_to notification.second_target.title, main_app.book_path(notification.second_target) %>
</div>

<div class=''>
  <% unless notification.target.blank? %>
    <div class="review-rating" data-score="<%= notification.target.rating %>"></div>
    <%= notification.target.comment %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

book.rb

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :chapters, dependent: :destroy

after_commit :create_notifications, on: :create

    def create_notifications
        self.user.followers.each do |follower|
          Notification.create(notify_type: 'book', 
                              actor: self.user,
                              user: follower, 
                              target: self, 
                              second_target: self.book)

        end
    end
```

So, if I've to render in the same partial, how should I? or maybe I've to do it another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of studying I got to know that a notify_type partial must be must be created which must also correspond to the book's notify_type.

i.e I created a

```
notify_type: "new_book"
```

Name of partial= '_new_book.html.erb'